# Update several UserDefaults files at the same time

Tags: swift, key, nsuserdefaults

I am writing a function that overwrites the value stored in several `UserDefaults` files.

These files `key` names are similar but have different terminations due to dynamic saving, ex:

`forKey:` `buyOrSellBitcoin-USD`

`forKey:` `buyOrSellBitcoin-GBP`

`forKey:` `buyOrSellBitcoin-CNY`

Is it possible to overwrite every file at the same with a single line like:

`forKey:` `buyOrSellBitcoin-\(x)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are not multiple `UserDefaults` files. It is a single key/value store. You write key/value pairs into the store.

No, there is no way to specify a wildcard that would somehow tell the OS to update all the keys you have defined that follow a particular pattern.

However, you can write collection objects like dictionaries into `UserDefaults`:

```
let coinsDict = [
  "buyOrSellBitcoin-USD": valueForUSD,
  "buyOrSellBitcoin-GBP": valueForGBP,
  "buyOrSellBitcoin-CNY": valueForCNY
]

UserDefaults.standard.set(coinsDict, forKey: "coinsDict")
```

And then you would read the resulting dictionary back from `UserDefaults` and unpack it into your data model.

Comment: Wow that's great!